# Jenkins - Active choice plugin - grovy script getting cleared after pipeline execution

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

using active choices to input data to pipeline. but once pipeline got executed, jenkins removes the grovy script for html controls.

[image]

I have approved the scripts from In-process Script approval section. but once I run the builds it's removes the grovy scripts also change the parameter type to Choice parameter. I need to keep this scripts to run the build again.